# Expand menu links down in a tree

Tags: 7, routes, theming, navigation

I'm using Nice menus, but it expands children sub menus to right only. I want it so that when you hove on main parent link, it drop-downs a sub-menu with all its children submenus expanded down in a tree.

There's some quality sketch I did as an example:
[image]

Doesn't have to be Nice-menus, any alternative modules are welcome. Cheers.

Comment: One quick thing you can do is implementing the solution using CSS, mostly this modules are showing and hiding the link using css only (diplay: none, or display: block). So just on hover event of parent link make display: block to nested ul li e.g: `ul.CLASS-PARENT-UL li:hover ul {display: block}`, something like can work.

Comment: If wants to use any alternative module then go for superfish menu module.

Comment: Okay but does it do the actual thing?

Comment: Go with a mega menu (there are a few, but look at [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) first) in combination with [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block)

Comment: Put it as answer please.